# Laravel - MySQL - Add foreign key to an existing column - Duplicate foreign key constraint name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel app and I have two tables, `invoices` and `items`. My items already have a column `invoice_id`, but it's not a foreign key.

When I check the structure in SequelAce, it shows `invoice_id` is a MUL key, in the index list below it lists `items_invoice_id_index` (foreign keys are shown as `..._foreign`).

I tried the combination of the following:

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('invoice_id'); // same error even if removed
    $table->unsignedInteger('invoice_id')->change(); // same error even if removed
    $table->integer('invoice_id')->unsigned()->index()->change(); // same error even if removed

    $table->foreign('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('invoices');
});
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'items_invoice_id_foreign' (SQL: alter table `items` add constraint `items_invoice_id_foreign` foreign key (`invoice_id`) references `invoices` (`id`))
```

My Laravel version is 5.6.

When I check table info, I see this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `items_invoice_id_index` (`invoice_id`),
CONSTRAINT `items_invoice_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_id`) REFERENCES `invoices` (`id`)
```

Does it mean that it's already foreign key? But I don't see any relationship when I generate a diagram. How do I fix this? I need to make a relation but not lose any data.

Comment: Table info says that It is already foreign key, so I think the problem is in your diagram generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the exception message is very clear: the `index` method marks the column as a foreign key so, when we say `$table->index('invoice_id')` this mark the `invoice_id` as a foreign key (**The column name must exist before executing this line**), and this line `$table->integer('invoice_id')->unsigned()->index()->change()` also makes `invoice_id` as a foreign key again, and this invalid approach so, your schema must be like so:

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('invoice_id');
    $table->foreign('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('invoices');
});
```

In case you want to use the `index` method, your schema must be like so:

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('invoice_id');
    $table->index('invoice_id');  // You can not execute this line before declaring the column name before
});
```

or briefly, you can do something like that

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('invoice_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. What is the difference between "index" method and your first example?

Comment: The three schemas are equivalents.